# Unwanted whitespace in Django urls

Tags: python, django, websocket

I have an unwanted whitespace in my url pattern and I think this is making trouble when I try to handshake my `Flutter` app with my `Django` backend. I know there are similar questions in answered on this, but I could not find where this comes from or how to fix it.. These are my URL patterns and when I try to handshake with the WebSocket, I'm getting the following error in `Django` terminal:

```
Not Found: /ws/chat_app/sjfAmH
"GET /ws/chat_app/sjfAmH HTTP/1.1" 404 4349
```

When I try to access the WebSocket endpoint in my browser, the 404 error shows up:

> Using the URLconf defined in project.urls, Django tried these
> URL patterns, in this order:
>
> 1. admin/
> 2. ws/ chat_app/(?P<unique_id>\w+)/$
>    Where, I spotted this unwanted whitespace.

Those are my URL patterns
[image: URL_patterns]

I have an Django app called `chat_app`, where I have defined my WebSocket consumer class. Then I added the routing, pointing at that consumers class in my `routing.py` file:

```
from django.urls import re_path
from .consumers import ChatConsumer

# The WebSocket URL pattern for chat rooms is defined by this code
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'chat_app/(?P<unique_id>\w+)/$', ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

Also, I have added the chat_app into `settings.py` installed apps and included the URL in my Django project `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from chat_app.routing import websocket_urlpatterns


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ...,
    path('ws/', include(websocket_urlpatterns)),
]
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @J_H I think this the most visible way to see, which URL patters django has tried and the whitespace in there.

Comment: @Geo: no there is not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whitespace is *not* part of the URL patterns itself. This is just how Django *lists* the patterns tried. The spaces are thus indications of include patterns, but these is not in the URL pattern itself.

If you thus visit a link with:

```
/ws/chat_app/sjfAmH/
```

it will fire. Notice the *trailing slash*. That is why the pattern did not match.